# What variable should replace "sentences"?

Tags: r, twitter, analytics, twitter-oauth

I'm new here and this is my first post. Sorry in advance if I don't format this properly. I'm currently working on school project using R. My goal is to conduct a sentiment analysis on the presidential debate using tweets. I've found a pre-made script online and have the basics of it working but I'm having trouble identifying which variable should be passed in to replace "sentences" and "sentence". Any ideas?

## The following errors get thrown for me:

Error: '\d' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'\d"
Error in iconv(sentence, "UTF-8", "ASCII") : object 'sentence' not found
Error in tolower(sentence) : object 'sentence' not found
Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'\s"
Error in unlist(word.list) : object 'word.list' not found

```
# Grab latest tweets
TrumpTweets_PostDebate <- searchTwitter(searchTerm1, maxTweets)

#Loop over tweets and extract text
library(plyr)
clean_TrumPostDebate = laply(TrumpTweets_PostDebate, function(t) t$getText())

# Read in dictionary of positive and negative works
yay = scan('/Users/KenKelemen/Downloads/opinion-lexicon-English/positive-words.txt',
           what='character', comment.char=';')
boo = scan('/Users/KenKelemen/Downloads/opinion-lexicon-English/negative-words.txt',
           what='character', comment.char=';')

# Add a few twitter-specific negative phrases
final_bad_text = c(boo, 'wtf', 'epicfail', 'douchebag', 'ass', 'douche', 'jerkoff')
final_good_text = c(yay, 'upgrade', ':)', '#iVoted', 'voted')
```

## I believe my problem lies within this section of the script w/ variables "sentences" and "sentence".

```
score.sentiment = function(sentences, final_good_text, final_bad_text, .progress='none')
{
  require("plyr")
  require("stringr")
  # we got a vector of sentences. plyr will handle a list
  # or a vector as an "l" for us
  # we want a simple array of scores back, so we use
  # "l" + "a" + "ply" = "laply":
  scores = laply(sentences, function(sentence, final_good_text, final_bad_text) {

# clean up sentences with R's regex-driven global substitute, gsub():
sentence = gsub('[[:punct:]]', '', sentence)
sentence = gsub('[[:cntrl:]]', '', sentence)
sentence = gsub('\d+', '', sentence)
#to remove emojis
sentence <- iconv(sentence, 'UTF-8', 'ASCII')
sentence = tolower(sentence)        
# split into words. str_split is in the stringr package
word.list = str_split(sentence, '\s+')
# sometimes a list() is one level of hierarchy too much
words = unlist(word.list)

# compare our words to the dictionaries of positive & negative terms
pos.matches = match(words, final_good_text)
neg.matches = match(words, final_bad_text)

# match() returns the position of the matched term or NA
# we just want a TRUE/FALSE:
pos.matches = !is.na(pos.matches)
neg.matches = !is.na(neg.matches)

# and conveniently enough, TRUE/FALSE will be treated as 1/0 by sum():
score = sum(pos.matches) - sum(neg.matches)

return(score)


 }, final_good_text, final_bad_text, .progress=.progress )

  scores.df = data.frame(score=scores, text=sentences)
  return(scores.df)
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose without some example data, but looking at your code, your instances of `\s` and `\d` in `gsub` and `strsplit` should be `\\s` and `\\d`. The "\" character needs to be escaped with an extra "\", weirdly.

Comment: Thanks a lot jdrobres. This answered my question and the script now runs. Now I just need to figure out how the rest works lol! Thanks again